# appsettings.json not found when running with `dotnet run --project`

Tags: .net, configuration, appsettings

I have a simple console app that loads `appsettings.json`:

```cs
var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
    .Build();
```

My `appsettings.json` file is being copied to the output on build according to setup in my csproj:

```xml
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="appsettings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
```

I noticed that the app works perfectly well when I run it with `dotnet run` from the app's directory (where the csproj is).
However, when I run it from the `.sln` file directory with `dotnet run --project ./source/MyProj/MyProj.csproj`, it throws:

```
Unhandled exception. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The configuration file 'appsettings.json' was not found and is not optional. The physical path is '/home/mnj/code/myapp/appsettings.json'.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationProvider.HandleException(ExceptionDispatchInfo info)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationProvider.Load(Boolean reload)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationProvider.Load()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationRoot..ctor(IList`1 providers)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilder.Build()
   at MyProj.Program.BuildServiceProvider() in /home/mnj/code/myapp/source/MyProj/Program.cs:line 24
   at MyProj.Program.Main(String[] args) in /home/marcin/code/myapp/source/MyProj/Program.cs:line 15
   at MyProj.Program.<Main>(String[] args)
```

Why dotnet properly loads `appsettings.json` from `source/MyProj/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/appsettings.json` when I invoke `dotnet run` from within project's directory, and it does not do it when I run it with `dotnet run --project ...`?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out I didn't need to use `.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())`. Removing that line solved the problem.